# why does this code give a access violation when run on msdev?

Tags: c, pointers

`while(*a++ = *b++){}` where a and b are valid char pointers.

Answer (score 11):

If b is a 10 character null terminated string and a is a buffer where 4 chars has been allocated, you'll write outside of allocated memory using the above code.

Answer (score 7):

One alternative answer:

```
char *a = "Hello";
char *b = "World";
```

These are both valid char pointers.  But a does not point to writable memory.

Answer (score 3):

The strings pointed to may not be null terminated meaning data is being read from and assigned to memory it should not have access to, hence the violation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like memory allocated for array 'a' is less than the length of the array 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it on MSDev, bung it in the debugger and step through it, and/or have a look at the actual memory areas where a and b are stored and see directly what's going on. It could be any of the things already mentioned as possibilities.